# How to read Diode Numbering System

Tags: diodes, components, component-selection, manufacturing, serial-number

How do I read diode numbers. I read that the numbering system for US diodes is the JEDEC system. But I don't think the JEDEC system applies to diode numbers after 1N. Everywhere I look I cant only find a way to interpret the first 2 letters/numbers, and I cant find anywhere to figure out the 4 numbers at the end. Plus, I cant know if the range of numbers I would be choosing is an available part anyway.

#### Update:

So I now know that the serial numbers on the part number dont really mean anything. So Is there any kind of **table** that shows a diodes varying currents, reverse voltages, etc... with the part numbers attached to it? If so please include a link. I have not found a table like that anywhere.

If not, how do others go about looking for diodes without any charts or tables.

Comment: You can search a distributor's website (Mouser, Digikey, Farnell...) for diodes or other components by many characteristics - and you'll find parts that are actually available to buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the first number represents the number of junctions in the device and the next letter (or two) represent the device type, the last four work as a serial number and do not carry any information directly. You need to look at a table to get the specific information about the device. In some circumstances, you may notice patterns in the numbering, like the 1N400X series matches the 1N539X series in that the last number indicates Vr but they don't use the same number to indicate that rating. In the case of the previously mentioned series, both series happen to use the number 1 as the last digit to represent a Vr = 50 V device, but once you get to the number 4, things progress differently. Some series start with the number 0 as the first number in the series, where others use the number 1 as the first. So, you can't really use that serial number to say anything about the ratings on the device. You need to look at the datasheet for the specific device series.

There is a table on Wikipedia, but you should verify accuracy with the datasheets.

[Wikipedia Page for 1N400X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1N400x_general-purpose_diodes)

Comment: @SchienceGeyser, Do you have an idea of where I can find a table like that?

Comment: Search for your specific number. If that number is part of a series, then there will be a table on the datasheet. Some numbers are NOT part of a series e.g.,  1N4000 is not in the same series as the 1N4001-7.